# How can I create Wordpress contact page to work without using any plugins?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to build my own contact page but i don't want to use any plugins. can any one tell me how to do it with your own fresh code or as a correction to my code i have mentioned below.
I also tried this one http://pastebin.ca/2332012
but got Message not sent error

I tried another way which gives Email sent successfully but I could recieve that mail in my hotmail.

Here are my codes.
Thanks in advance.
**Validation part**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if(trim($_POST['sender_name']) === '') {
    $nameError = 'Please enter your name.';
    $hasError = true;
  } else {
    $name = trim($_POST['sender_name']);
  }

  if(trim($_POST['sender_email']) === '')  {
    $emailError = 'Please enter your email address.';
    $hasError = true;
  } else if (!preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i", trim($_POST['sender_email']))) {
    $emailError = 'You entered an invalid email address.';
    $hasError = true;
  } else {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
  }

  if(trim($_POST['message']) === '') {
    $messageError = 'Please enter a message.';
    $hasError = true;
  } else {
    if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
      $message = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
    } else {
      $message = trim($_POST['message']);
    }
  }

if(trim($_POST['subject']) === '') {
    $subjectError = 'Please enter a subject.';
    $hasError = true;
  } else {
    if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
      $subject = stripslashes(trim($_POST['subject']));
    } else {
      $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
    }
  }

  if(!isset($hasError)) {
    $emailTo = get_option('tz_email');
    if (!isset($emailTo) || ($emailTo == '') ){
      $emailTo = get_option('admin_email');
    }
    //$subject = '[PHP Snippets] From '.$name;
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nMessage: $message\n\n Subject: $subject";
    $headers = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;
  }

} ?>
```

above code starts above get_header() part

**HTML:**

```
<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="" id="contactForm"><div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">

          <label for="name">Name <span class="required">*</span></label>


      <input type="text" name="sender_name" value="" class="form-control" id="name" required="required" placeholder="Enter Your Name or Organization" rows="5" cols="80"  />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">

            <label for="email">Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <div class="input-group">



       <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>


      <input type="text" name="sender_email" value="" class="form-control" id="email" required="required" placeholder="Enter Your Email id" rows="5" cols="80"  />      </div><!--input g ends  -->
     </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <p>
              <label for="subject">Subject <span class="required">*</span></label>


              <br /><select name="subject" class = "form-control" id="subject" required="required">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select a subject</option>
<option value="value1">General Customer Service</option>
<option value="value2">Setup a meeting for collabration</option>
<option value="value3">Product Support</option>
<option value="value4">Suggestion</option>
</select>      </p>                                       
      </div>
  </div>

     <div class="col-md-6">

           <div class="form-group">

          <p>
                  <label for="message">Message <span class="required">*</span></label>


            <textarea name="message" cols="25" rows="9" class="form-control" id="message" required="required" placeholder="Write your message" ></textarea>          </p>
          </div>
    </div>

   <div class="col-md-12">

  <p>
          <br/><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="btnContactUs"  />  </p>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
</form>
```

Comment: Is there a problem with your code? Need to be more specific with your question

Comment: @Andrew  I don't know exactly. It gives me success message but I am not receiving any email even after 1 hour.

Comment: @Robin have you followed any tutorial or you created your own? 
i guess, sometimes this tutorial will help you. 
Link :
http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-and-why/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a copy of page.php file and change it's name to page-contact.php .
add this PHP code before `<?php get_header(); ?>` :

```
<?php

      //response generation function

      $response = "";

      //function to generate response
      function my_contact_form_generate_response($type, $message){

        global $response;

        if($type == "success") $response = "<div class='success'>{$message}</div>";
        else $response = "<div class='error'>{$message}</div>";

      }

      //response messages
      $not_human       = "Human verification incorrect.";
      $missing_content = "Please supply all information.";
      $email_invalid   = "Email Address Invalid.";
      $message_unsent  = "Message was not sent. Try Again.";
      $message_sent    = "Thanks! Your message has been sent.";

      //user posted variables
      $name = $_POST['message_name'];
      $email = $_POST['message_email'];
      $message = $_POST['message_text'];
      $human = $_POST['message_human'];

      //php mailer variables
      $to = get_option('admin_email');
      $subject = "Someone sent a message from ".get_bloginfo('name');
      $headers = 'From: '. $email . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";

      if(!$human == 0){
        if($human != 2) my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $not_human); //not human!
        else {

          //validate email
          if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $email_invalid);
          else //email is valid
          {
            //validate presence of name and message
            if(empty($name) || empty($message)){
              my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);
            }
            else //ready to go!
            {
              $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($message), $headers);
              if($sent) my_contact_form_generate_response("success", $message_sent); //message sent!
              else my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $message_unsent); //message wasn't sent
            }
          }
        }
      }
      else if ($_POST['submitted']) my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);

?>
```

Then, put this HTML code inside this file as the contact form :

```
<div id="respond">
            <?php echo $response; ?>
            <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
              <p><label for="name">Name: <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" name="message_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_name']); ?>"></label></p>
              <p><label for="message_email">Email: <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" name="message_email" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_email']); ?>"></label></p>
              <p><label for="message_text">Message: <span>*</span> <br><textarea type="text" name="message_text"><?php echo esc_textarea($_POST['message_text']); ?></textarea></label></p>
              <p><label for="message_human">Human Verification: <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" style="width: 60px;" name="message_human"> + 3 = 5</label></p>
              <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
              <p><input type="submit"></p>
            </form>
</div>
```

And finally, this is a minimal styling for the form :

```
.error{
              padding: 5px 9px;
              border: 1px solid red;
              color: red;
              border-radius: 3px;
            }

            .success{
              padding: 5px 9px;
              border: 1px solid green;
              color: green;
              border-radius: 3px;
            }

            form span{
              color: red;
 }
```

Reference :

http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-and-why/

Comment: @Pay4m Mail not sent Message. I am using WAMP. Trying to figure out whether its WAMP server problem or PHP codes in WP

Comment: That's exactly because you are on a localhost. When you upload your website, it will work. I had the same problem and it's working on my website

Comment: @Pay4m How can I use this form to send email to user with editor role or both editor and admin.. I only know about admin email things

Answer (score 0):

You should make a template for contact-us page. Just make a PHP file in your template folder. And in that file you have to write code for 2 lines like this.

```
/**
 * Template Name: Contact-us
 *
 *
 * @package ABC
 *
 * 
 */
```

Then after you have to create new page in your admin panel and assign this template name. Then after make a contact-us form.